# extension function for Kotlin data class

Tags: android, function, kotlin, data-class, kotlin-extension

I have a data class which looks something like this

```
data class SuggestionResponse(
  val metadata: Metadata,
  val response: Response
)

data class Response(
 ///blah blah
)

data class Metadata(
  val timeleft: String,
  val totalTime: String
)
```

Now my requirement to transform this data into a different type of data object.I  want to write an extension function to do this task. let the name of function be hello

I would like to call this extension function like this

`suggestionResponse.hello()`

how do I write the extension function?.any help would be appreciated

Comment: `fun SuggestionResponse.hello() { /* do magic */ }`?

Comment: I want to use the details in the `suggestionResponse` inside the extension function.how do I access it

Comment: use `this` keyword to denote the current instance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create an extension function on `SuggestionResponse` class and you'll have access to the properties of `SuggestionResponse` class:

```
fun SuggestionResponse.hello() { 
    //`metadata` property is available here
    //`response` property is available here
    val time = metadata.timeleft
}
```

And then you'll be able to call it on an instance of `SuggestionResponse` class:

```
suggestionResponse.hello()
```

[More info about extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).